# Freemarker date assignment to seemingly Valid Date Fails

Tags: java, spring, templates, spring-mvc, freemarker

I'm running into a weird problem that doesn't seem to happen all the time, but when it does, it looks like this:

```
Error: on line 60, column 31 in foo/bar.ftl
Expecting a date here, found: 2011-12-29 04:37AM
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> assignment: createDate=project.createdTime?datetime("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mma") [on line 60, column 9 in foo/bar.ftl]
----------

Java backtrace for programmers:
----------
freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: Error: on line 60, column 31 in foo/bar.ftl
Expecting a date here, found: 2011-12-29 04:37AM
    at freemarker.core.BuiltIn$dateBI$DateParser.parse(BuiltIn.java:334)
    at freemarker.core.BuiltIn$dateBI$DateParser.get(BuiltIn.java:305)
    at freemarker.core.BuiltIn$dateBI$DateParser.exec(BuiltIn.java:316)
    at freemarker.core.MethodCall._getAsTemplateModel(MethodCall.java:93)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
    at freemarker.core.Assignment.accept(Assignment.java:90)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:190)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.processTemplate(FreeMarkerView.java:366)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.doRender(FreeMarkerView.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.renderMergedTemplateModel(FreeMarkerView.java:233)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractTemplateView.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
...
```

The line in bar.ftl where it's failing looks like this:

```
<#assign createDate = project.createdTime?datetime("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mma")>
```

The getter in the Project.java code looks like this:

```
private Date createdTime;
...
public String getCreatedTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat sm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mma");
    return createdTime == null ? null : sm.format(createdTime);
}
```

So to me, it looks like everything is getting returned correctly, and that the code is setup correctly.  I'm using FreeMarker 2.3.16 and Spring MVC.  It seems to work most of the time, but fails sometimes...

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means that, internally, `DateFormat.parse` has thrown `java.text.ParseException`. Since the string given in the exception message should be parsed OK with that pattern (and I hope your example is exact and real), and since it happens only sometimes, it stinks like a concurrency (multi-threading) issue around the date-format cache. If you could construct a standalone test that demonstrates this, that would make finding it quicker (I'm in charge of maintaining FM, pretty much). Quickly looking at the source code nothing jumps at me... the syncs are there.

Edit: Another possible reason is that sometimes the FreeMarker "locale" setting is not English. The "AM"/"PM" postfix is different for non-English, and so it causes this error.

Comment: My example is exact and real, except I've replaced the file names with foo and bar respectively...  I think both you and ChssPly76 have helped me here.  I do agree that it's probably a concurrency issue.  Although a band-aid solution, I think I'm going to go with ChssPly76's suggestion, and avoid using the parsing pattern altogether.  I'm assuming this would also avoid the date-format cache?

Comment: I'm on FreeMarker version 2.3.16.   Would moving to a newer version potentially help?

Comment: It wouldn't avoid the date-format cache, because it's also used when convertin a `Date` to `String`. However, if the issue is specific to the `parse` method, then it avoids it. Upgrading from 2.3.16 will not help, as this bug (if it's a FreeMarker bug anyway) was unknown so far.

Comment: Another idea as the reason of the failure... Is it possible that sometimes the FreeMarker "locale" setting is not English? The "AM"/"PM" postfix is different for non-English, and so it causes this error.

Comment: ddekany -- You may be on to something with the "locale" setting.  Most of the successful users are from US. The one that seems to fail is from Russia.. I will investigate this further. Thanks!!  If that's the case, is there an elegant way to parse?  Just leave out the 'a' parse flag?

Comment: Simply, the locale setting of FreeMarker should be in sync with the locale setting used in `getCreatedTime()`. Also the time-zones must be in sync, or else that two pieces of code will misunderstand each other. That's why you should never pass around dates in localized format, and I guess that's what you should address here. If you can't use `Date` objects for some reason, use ISO 8601 dates with UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks valid, I've no idea why it fails - especially "sometimes".

One thing that strikes me as odd, however, is that you're converting your date to string first (inside `getCreatedTime()`) only to parse it back within FreeMarker template. Why not pass it as date to begin with? Something like:

```
// Project.java
public Date getCreatedTime() {
    return this.createdTime;
}

// bar.ftl
<#assign createDate = project.createdTime?datetime>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The root cause is actually some concurrent issue, that I'm going to further investigate